# Adding two TextBlocks in one column of the WPF project

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I want to add two TextBlocks in one column of my WPF project. I use the following codes but They locate on eachother now. How may I insert them after each other (not on each other)? Please note that I don't want to put them in two seperate columns.

```
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1"  x:Name="FirstName" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1"  x:Name="LastName" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
```

Comment: Use a `StackPanel` - or use different `Grid.Row` values.

Comment: Why is there `Grid.ColumnSpan="2"` on the second TextBlock when you want to put both in one column? Put both in a horizontal StackPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a WrapPanel to host the TextBlocks horizontally:

```
  <WrapPanel Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <TextBlock x:Name="FirstName" Margin="10,10,0,0" Text="FirstName" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="LastName" Margin="10,10,0,0" Text="LastName" />
    </WrapPanel>
```